# How do I create an index page that loop through the table fields of its entries?

Tags: templating, forloop, table-field, table

Every entry in a section has a table.  The table depicts sales over 7 years.

**I want to create an `index page` that lists the title of each entry and the sales for each entry in the section.**

I know how to loop through the table fields to template the table for each entry.

I know how to loop through the titles of each entry to create an index page.

**But, how do I create an index page that loops through the table data for each entry?**

Simple index loop:

```
{% for item in craft.entries.section('widgets').all() %}
    <li>{{ item.title }}</li>        
{% endfor %}
```

The entry table format is as follows:

```
{% set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('budgetTable') %}   

        <table id="apaf" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead >
                <tr>
                    {% for column in field.settings.columns %}
                    <th scope="col" style="font-weight: bold;">{{ column.heading }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>    
            </thead>     

            <tbody>
                {% for row in entry.budgetTable %}
                <tr>    

                    <th scope="row" style="font-weight: bold;">{{ row.widgetTitle }}</th>

                </tr>          
                {% endfor %}

            </tbody>          
        </table>
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following 100%.  `budgetTable` is the name of the Table field. Does it only have 1 column with a handle of `widgetTitle`?

Comment: @Brad Bell.  I only depict 1 column handle.  There are actually 10.